# What are you eating?

Tags: riddle, word

SZ#001

> You throw away the outside and cook the inside. Then you eat the outside and throw away the inside. What did you just eat?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This particular puzzle is an old chestnut and a simple Google search gives the answer. We tend to prefer puzzles/riddles which require more than googling in this site. Hope you create a new and better puzzle soon.

Comment: I will keep that in mind @Sid. This was one riddle I remembered since long ago and I wanted to ask.

Comment: @ShashankKuchibhotla I don't really know if it's the popular opinion but I think that for almost identical answers you should accept the first, since Phylyp answered before Riley and Pugmonkey, I think it should be his.

Comment: @Saeïdryl I accepted Pugmonkey's answer since he was the first one to answer. I will change the correct answer it's understood that the most identical plus fastest answer.

Comment: @ShashankKuchibhotla Pugmonkey's answer was posted at 12:34:27 while Phylyp's was at 12:33:00. You can see the timestamps by hovering over the 'answered x hours ago' text.

The position in the list of answers is not only affected by the time it took to answer. I assume you checked the highest one, assuming it was the first answer.

Comment: I believe that multiple answers with an identical number of votes are ordered ***randomly***.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's

> Corn

Because

> You throw away the leaves covering the ear of corn, and then boil/cook the inside. You then eat the kernels but then throw away the center piece.

This is a chestnut, a riddle commonly asked in magazines and the internet.

Answer (score 18):

I have seen the answers, but why isn't it...

> Chicken

You throw away the outside and cook the inside

> You throw away the feathers and cook the chicken.

Then you eat the outside and throw away the inside

> You eat the chicken, and throw away the bones.

Answer (score 4):

You ate

> corn on the cob

You throw away the outside and cook the inside

> You shuck the corn and throw away the leafy covering

Then you eat the outside and throw away the inside

> You eat the kernels and throw away the cob

Answer (score 2):

You ate

> Corn. You throw away the husk and cook the inside. Then you eat the outside of the cob and throw the cob away.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it might be

> meringue

since

> you throw out the eggshell and the yolk, only eating the egg white

Comment: Except you don't cook the yolk when you're making meringue. Nice try though! Welcome to puzzling...

Answer (score 2):

I bought a package of chocolate peanuts. I threw away the packaging, then sucked the chocolate off the peanuts and threw the peanuts away.

Comment: But you haven't cooked them. Otherwise you would have a pool of concentrated chocolate.